# android how to create fisheye effect on jpeg

Tags: android, image-processing, fisheye

I'm wanting to distort a jpeg image in android. The distortion is a fisheye effect. Are there any libraries i can import into android that i can use to achieve this effect.

thanks mat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps canvas.drawBitmapMesh(...) could do it. There is an example in ApiDemos under com.example.android.apis.graphics / BitmapMesh.java

In your Exclipse create a new Android project and select "Create project from existing sample". Choose target android version and then ApiDemos.

Run the application and see an effect of this method in Graphics/BitmapMesh

Comment: Ok thanks, had a look. I might try to find a fisheye algorithm that I can use in the bitmapmesh app.